# Making the contents in <td> element static position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table and my webpage as

```
 <table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         .....  
         .....
      </td>
      <td>
          <img src="mylogo.jpg"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

the contents of the first `<td>` is changing dynamically. so the height of this `<td>` is also changing. this dynamic changing is affecting the second `<td>` as the position of the image is also changing.
How can i make the image in a static place in that `<td>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you meant that the the picture's position always changes to center of the `<td>`??

then you can add `valign="top"` property to the td which contains your image

so, not caring how long your first `<td>` is the image will stay at top of the `<td>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS:

```
#mytable{
  position:relative;
}
#myimage{
    position:absolute;
    top: ___;
    left: ___;
}
```

Replace `___` with the desired distance.

**Edit:**

But if what you want is a background, then you could better use:

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">
   <tr>
      <td>
         .....  
         .....
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#mytable{ 
    background: url('mylogo.jpg');
}
```

And if you want to adjust the position, see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: to which elements i have to add these id's.

Comment: To the table and image elements

Comment: @gamehelp16 Yes, I know w3schools sometimes is wrong or shows bad practises, and should be a public wiki (and I have read w3fools before). But in general it's a good reference and has helped me a lot.

Comment: @oriol: I don't say that w3schools is really bad. I just share so many people know mistakes in w3schools and avoid studying from the wrong examples